# When Jsoup parse Html tag that only included "0", null will be returned?

Tags: java, jsoup

I use jsoup-1.6.0，parse html tag string, that only include string content "0", but jsoup return null, I understand...

examply:

```
String html = "<span>0</span>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Elements eles = doc.getElementsByTag("span");
Element span = eles.get(0);
System.out.println(span.hasText());//false
System.out.println(span.ownText());//null, but I hope the result is "0"
```

It's why?

---

Answer:

It should be a bug, binary_runner says jsoup-1.3.3 works well, I test jsoup-1.5.2 works well too. so, I decide use jsoup-1.5.2 .

Thanks binary_runner!

Comment: Report it. http://jsoup.org/bugs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [bug](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/issues/107) in jsoup `1.6.0` caused by an incorrect null check in the new HTML parser implementation.

I have [fixed the issue](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/commit/0c9ccf770b8cd61d67480a010348aeab5016a942) and it will be available in `1.6.1`, which I'll in the next couple of days.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure. probably, i guess, it's a Jsoup's bug. I could `a` with following code.

```
String html = "<span>a</span>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Elements eles = doc.getElementsByTag("span");
Element span = eles.get(0);
System.out.println(span.hasText());//true
System.out.println(span.ownText());//"a"
```

Comment: binary_runner says it should be a bug.I test jsoup-1.5.2, works well.

Comment: Jonathan Hedley says it will be available in 1.6.1.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly a bug, works well with JSoup 1.3.3 .

Comment: Yes, you are right.I test jsoup-1.5.2, works well too.I decide use 1.5.2 .

Comment: I'm glad my information helped. Would you accept it as answer ?

And please report the bug if such does not already exist.

Comment: Your answer really helps me, but Jonathan Hedley's answer is very detailed.I think it is helpful to others, so I have to choose it.I'm sorry.